# Recreating Thrift clients in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, thrift

Shortly, our project uses a Thrift server and mobile clients with multiplexing.

While I was developing the iOS client, I encountered a strange problem;

When I first created the client and made calls, it is OK and it works as expected.

Since there is no close method for Cocoa Thrift client, I am hoping ARC will take care of it.

After some time, I create another client for the same service and do the same things, but this time, when I made a service call, client hangs and after some time in throws a "'TTransportException', reason: 'Cannot read. Remote side has closed.'".

In the server, operation is successfully completed and the value returned.

Does anybody have an idea about what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Reading your question i remembered that we encountered a very similar problem in very a different environment. If ARC takes care of your client and closes the connection, especially the port, this might be the reason why recreating the client again with the same port is the root of your problem. Opening the same port shortly after closing it can take a very long time (minutes) depending on timeouts.

Sorry no real answer to your problem but maybe a hint were to look for.